# Custom sheet with storyboard

Tags: objective-c, macos

From 10.10 beginSheet:modalFor... to get a custom sheet is deprecated for beginSheet:completionHandler:
So with storyboard I used only a NSViewController to "NSWindow" like customSheetView.view.window.
This my code but nothing nothing is happening when I press my btn.

```
#import "vv.h"
@property (strong) vv *customSheetView;

@synthesize customSheetView;

- (IBAction)displayCustomSheet:(id)sender {

if (!customSheetView) {
    customSheetView = [[NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"sheet"];
}

//[[NSApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0]
[customSheetView.view.window beginSheet:self.view.window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
                           switch (result) {
                               case 0:
                                   self.outputLabel.stringValue = @"ok";
                                   break;

                               case 1:
                                   self.outputLabel.stringValue = @"cancel";
                                   break;

                               default:
                                   self.outputLabel.stringValue = @"You did something";
                                   break;
                           } 
                       }];   
}
```

Comment: Try logging `customSheetView.view.window` to make sure it's not nil, perhaps?

Comment: Yes is nil. Something like `customSheetView = [[vv alloc] init];` ?

Comment: Instead of `beginSheet`, present the sheet with `presentViewControllerAsSheet`.

Comment: Ok but there isn’t a ‘completionHandler’

Comment: How is the sheet dismissed?

Comment: `customSheetView.view.window` is going to be `nil` until you add the view to a window. It doesn't matter how you create the view controller; if you haven't put it in a window, the view's `window` property will be `nil`. And of course when you send a message to `nil`, nothing happens.

Comment: Actually, looking at this again, I think you have an additional problem; your parameters are backwards. `[customSheetView.view.window beginSheet:self.view.window` means that `self.view.window` would be the sheet, and `customSheetView.view.window` would be the parent window, which I think is probably the opposite of what you wanted. Not that this makes a difference, though, with the sheet window being `nil`. Best solution to the problem is to use `presentViewControllerAsSheet` as @Willeke suggested.

Comment: Without storyboard I can add element in the window (sheet) and have completionHandler. With storyboard I must have a nswindowcontroller witch contains a nsviewcontroller. Then with only a nsviewcontroller with presentViewControllerAsSheet there isn’t completionHandler. You're right this is the best solution to show a sheet but for me Apple has taken a step back, there are too many limits.